# Discord.NET Kick Command

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, discord, discord.net

So I have a bot I'm working on for a computer science project, and my kick command isn't working. I've tried commenting out the update SQL and the ReplyAsync lines but it just won't kick the user. Am I using the wrong datatype for the user?

```
public class Kick : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbDataAdapter da;

        [Command("kick")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)]
        [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)]
        public async Task KickUser(IGuildUser user, string reason = "No reason provided")
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=BotDB.accdb";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            con.Open();
            da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand($"UPDATE UserData SET NumKick = NumKick + 1 WHERE UserID = '{Convert.ToString(user.Id)}'");
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            await ReplyAsync($"{user.Nickname} was kicked from the server for '{reason}'");
            await user.KickAsync(reason);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you receiving an error, or is nothing happening at all?

Comment: No errors anywhere, it just does nothing. Console logs don't have any errors either

Comment: Your command is either not executing or your command is throwing an error. You can use a try catch. Discord.Net has an error handling that is why you can't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, I had to remove the default value for string reason, and in the InsertCommand area I forgot to state the OleDbConnection after the SQL.